# Distributed configurations that differs by instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, distributed

I have a design question I would like different ideas or optimal solutions for.

If I have a single application that needs to be deployed across 100-1000's of different computes, with the goal of listening to different messaging queues/topics per instance, without repeating topics already being listened to how would one go about this.

- Instance 1 -> register itself to some tool -> grab unique topic1 properties
- Instance 2 -> register itself to same tool -> grab unique topic2 properties
- Instance X -> ...

Where the tool may be able to keep track of all the possible properties, and possibly the health of instances(to possibly allow a new instance to take its property or alert)

I would prefer not to have X number of properties files within the message listening application, but rather a centralized tool that can have 1 or many properties that do not repeat per instance.

I have ideas how to make this application in a custom way, but would like to know if there are tools that do this already.

My application is a java spring boot app if that helps.